# How to track redirection time in ASP.NET 

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a comparison shopping system website which will display Amazon products. I have a functionality in it to generate url for any product and we can put that url for advertisement and when someone click on that advertisement control will first come to my website and then it will redirected to amazon project detail page. Now i want to track total time between reaching and leaving of control on my website. I want to track redirection time.

Please help me, sorry about my bad english.

Comment: You want the time from "user clicks in your page" to "user sees other page"? I don't think you can do that server-side, if you don't control that other page. You need to have something that sends the time to the server *after* the page has loaded, which means javascript in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at Firebug. This tool can help you measure a lot of things on your website.

They can also measure redirect times. [Here](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/page-load-analysis-using-firebug/) is some documentation.

Comment: firebug will only work with morzilla firefox and i also need to store reaching-time and leaveing-time in database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use session time. so you can start a timer when session starts, store it in session and end the timer when session ends.

Comment: how to use session time ... do you have any link for sample code or any other help?